# Struggling with DisplayLink all day - now I cannot gain access to X11 at all - how to reset things?

Tags: networking, displaylink

Not sure what I did but I get "Failed to start DisplayLink Driver Service". I had tried to remove it (in recovery mode) but it seems Networking does not work in recovery mode (even if I enable it.) When I attempt to ping, I get "Temporary failure in name resolution". Most solutions I find suggest changing the /etc/resolve.conf file - but systemd-resolved is not active on Ubuntu (or it works differently via resolvectl which is not well documented.) I tried executing the resolvectl dns command: resolvectl dns wpl3s0 8.8.8.8 - but that did not work

Comment: It's probably much simpler than the convoluted way you're approaching the problem. "Failed to start... driver" usually means there's something preventing (unsigned) drivers from loading and that "something" typically is Secure Boot enabled in UEFI. Unless you're dual-booting with Windows 11 you can and, for convenience only, should disable it.

Comment: Thanks - I was able to use Windows (10) and connect to the filesystem and offload my files. I will use WSL for now. It seems the setup of the dual boot was not done properly (but not really sure.) I hesitate to change anything now - lots of warnings about changing this setting.